# Input text to a PickList in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have converted my

```
 <%= f.text_field :customer_poc %>
```

to

```
<%= f.collection_select(:customer_poc, Project.all, :customer_poc, :customer_poc, :include_blank => "Please select") %>
```

This creates a PickList and allows me to select from all of the Customer POC choices in the Db. However, now I cannot enter new data.

What do I need to add so I can have my picklist but also be able to input new data into the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an unbound text field tag to add new data, and keep your collection_select for the PickList. For instance:

```
<%= f.text_field_tag :new_customer_poc %>
```

When you're processing params, you'll need to check whether `params[:new_customer_poc]` was filled in, and if so then create a new record from it.